# How to make my code more efficient so it has a runtime of less than 1sec

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration, runtime

I had a test recently (it's over now) and I had this question:
[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFry5.png)

and I could do the question. However there was one test case at the end that said that we get an extra 10 marks if the runtime of that case is <1s. However, my issue was that I could not get the runtime to be below 1sec. My code and the test case are below. Also I should add we're not allowed to import any packages.

Test case:

```
longList = [i for i in range(100000)]
print(calculateAreas(longList,longList[::-1]))
```

My code:

```
def calculateAreas(w_list,h_list):
    width_length = len(w_list)
    height_length = len(h_list)
    list_of_areas = []
    red_area = 0
    white_area = 0
    yellow_area = 0
    for i in range(width_length):
        for n in range(height_length):
            if (i+n-2) % 3 == 0:
                red_area += (w_list[i] * h_list[n])
            if (i+n-2) % 3 == 1:
                white_area += (w_list[i] * h_list[n])
            if (i+n-2) % 3 == 2:
                yellow_area += (w_list[i] * h_list[n])
    list_of_areas.insert(0, white_area)
    list_of_areas.insert(1, yellow_area)
    list_of_areas.insert(2, red_area)
    tuple_area = tuple(list_of_areas)
    return tuple_area
```

Comment: If you want efficiency over all else python is not the way to go, try using C++

Comment: You could run a profiler on your code, this should return you the most time consuming steps. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html). I would suggest running it sorted by `tottime`, as this is what you want to reduce.

Comment: @Evorage If you read the question you can clearly see that this is an assignment meant to be solved in python. So please don't just blindly comment "C++ fAsTEr".

Comment: Just to be sure: Are you sure about the Test Case with `len(longList) = 100000`? For the case one order of magnitude lower (`len(longList) = 10000`) I would have a solution (~0.3s), but this test case is currently at 27s (at least on my machine...).

Comment: @venky__ if you noticed I only commented a suggestion I didn't answer the question therefore my comment is valid

Comment: @Jakob yup, that’s the exact test case given to us

Comment: @fatburgerrr Also ask your classmates and professor. If you ever gen an answer post it here. Intriguing problem.

Comment: @venky__ I will do that, but I'm not sure when they'll give the answer or if they even will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the way to speed up is using list comprehension and trying to make only the necessary operations. There is a pattern on the both axis of white -> yellow -> red -> white..., we can use list comprehension to separate these colors and then find the total area of each one of them.
to separate a color in a axis we can use:

```
list[::3]
```

so say we could sum up all the white values on the w_list[0] and multiply by the sum of all white values on the h_list[0], we would get about 1/3 of whites total value. So we could repeate this for w_list[1] with h_list[1] and w_list[2] with h_list[2]. In short, what I'm trying to do is separate white with 3 grids like this one

```
W--W--W-
+--+--+-
+--+--+-
W--W--W-
+--+--+-
```

slightly dislocated one from the other and using list comprehension to isolate and get the area without having to make nested for loops:

```
def calculateAreas(w_list, h_list):
    white = 0
    yellow = 0
    red = 0
    for i, j in zip([0,1,2], [0,2,1]):
        white += sum(w_list[i::3]) * sum(h_list[j::3])
        yellow += sum(w_list[i::3]) * sum(h_list[(j+1)%3::3])
        red += sum(w_list[i::3]) * sum(h_list[(j+2)%3::3])
    return (white, yellow, red)
```

this way we are only passing 3 times threw the for loop and on a list of 100000 elements it's timing 0.0904s on my slow laptop. If I can give you a couple tips about your code: 1- try to interact directly over the list elements (use enumerate) 2- use 'elif' and 'else' statements (if a color checked 'white', you dont need to check if its red). And in general, if you need to speed up a code, try avoiding nested loops, imagine interacting every element in one list with every other element in another list: thats len(list)**2!